# Is there an equivalent of VirtualAlloc on Android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk, virtual-memory

I'm looking into virtual memory management with android ndk and was wondering if there is an equivalent to the VirtualAlloc/Free family of functions in the android ndk, and if so, where can I find some docs on them.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, all memory allocations are "virtual", in the sense that the memory is not committed unless it is really accessed. If I remember correctly, VirtualAlloc comes from Windows CE, where the memory per process was artificially limited to 32 MByte (see http://denniskrabbe.wordpress.com/2009/10/09/windows-mobile-heaps-from-the-large-memory-area/). On Android, the limitations are the natural ones of a 32-bit architecture (iOS has recently entered the 64-bit era). There are some limitations on the JVM heap size, but they do not apply to native (NDK) memory (see [Maximum native memory that can be allocated to an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087563/maximum-native-memory-that-can-be-allocated-to-an-android-app))

In Android, just like any Linux, malloc is optimistic, which means you can encounter out-of-memory after your malloc succeeded, see [Does malloc lazily create the backing pages for an allocation on Linux (and other platforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911860/does-malloc-lazily-create-the-backing-pages-for-an-allocation-on-linux-and-othe). On the other hand, bionic does not provide [custom memory allocation hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) as glibc.

Comment: Does this mean that I should be using malloc/new to handle memory? In VirtualAlloc I can request to reserve or commit explicitly, how do I do this in android native?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  (I'm feeling a little http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem here.)

Comment: No, in Android (neither in bionic nor in the Linux kernel) one can not request to reserve or commit explicitly.