# What is the NDK memory limit for an app on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, memory-limit

There are really old posts on SO that suggest that there is not real memory limit on Android NDK ([Maximum native memory that can be allocated to an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087563/maximum-native-memory-that-can-be-allocated-to-an-android-app)). Is this still true?

I have a memory intensive program written in c++ which I am calling on Android. This is taking quite an unusual amount of time to run. To me, this suggests that there is a memory hard limit that the program is using.

I would like an update on this since NDK memory related posts are quite old.

Comment: To figure out why it's slow, try the profiler: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler

Answer (score 0):

Why do not just try a "malloc()" using a very big number like 500MB or 1GB? It will be more easy and quick than ask a question and wait an answer somewhere...

However **there isn't any limit to memory allocation using NDK** (only using malloc and similar methods). Instead using reflection via NDK (like Java objects creation from NDK) follows normal JVM limits.